# Andorid NDK | How to determine which C++ standard supported by NDK 9c

Tags: android, c++, c++11, android-ndk, compiler-flags

I want to try new features of c++ (especially C++11) on my Android native project.

How to determine which C++ Standard supported by NDK Revision 9c?

**Update**

For instance in case

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
for(int& e : arr)
{
    e = e*e;
}
```

I got

```
error: range-based-for loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
```

Is this means that NDK support only C++98 Standard?

Comment: How about compiling something nice?

Comment: there is gcc 4.8 and clang 3.3 support, so that means pretty much everything from C++11, modulo bugs.

Comment: @TemplateRex, Why in this case I got error?

Comment: because C++98 does not support range-for loops. You need to compile with `-std=c++11` mode.

Comment: @TemplateRex, thanks! If you will write answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [**Android NDK docs**](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html), version 9c supports gcc 4.8 and Clang 3.3, both of which are fully C++11 compliant. To actually make use of C++11, you need to compile with the flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: I've enabled my build for C++11 but I'm still unable to build with a range `for`; I get errors like: `foo.cpp:83:33: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope` - any idea what might be going on? I'm using `stlport_static` if it makes a difference (I can't use gnustl due to another library I depend on).

Comment: @fluffy if you are using any kind of 3rd-party STL version, then all bets are off. You might want to consult the docs of your STL to see whether they support C++11 or beyond.

Comment: I know the version of STLPort bundled with the Android NDK does not have explicit C++11 support yet, but I was hoping that range for would work anyway, since it provides the same iterator semantics. Apparently not, though, so I'll just use `BOOST_FOREACH` (which works fine). Thanks.

Comment: it depends on whether your STL provides non-member `begin()` and `end()` for C-arrays. You should be able to use range-for on `std::vector` e.g., because there range-for will fall back to the member `.begin()` and `.end()`

Comment: It was on a `std::deque` that I was trying it, and got that error. Which is why the particular errors I was getting were so bizarre. Oh well. Maybe someday real life will catch up to the future of 2011. :)